# IOS: Retrieve number of managed objects in entity

Tags: ios, core-data, count

I have based the following code on the numerous answers to getting a count of objects in an entity but my code is giving a gigantic number, not the correct one.  Does it have something to do with NSUInteger or is there an error in how I am retrieving the count?

```
- (NSUInteger) retrieveNumberBooks {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Books"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSCountResultType;
    NSError *fetchError= nil;
    NSNumber *userid = @5;//for testing
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@", userid];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
    [fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:NO];


    NSUInteger itemsCount=[_managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest  error:&fetchError];
    if ((itemsCount=NSNotFound)) {
    NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@",fetchError);
                                    }
    return itemsCount;
}


 - (void)updateInterface {
        NSUInteger *numberBooks = [self retrieveNumBooks];
NSLog(@"number books%d",numberBooks);
```

gives 2147483647 when there are only a few test objects stored.

**Edit:**  Following code works correctly after you load MOC:

```
 -(NSUInteger) retrieveNumBooks {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSUInteger count = [_managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if(count == NSNotFound) {
            // Handle error
        }

        return count;

    }
```

Comment: You're calling `retrieveNumChallengers` instead of `retrieveNumberBooks`, so the result can be anything.

Comment: Sorry, that was typo.  Should be books.

Comment: It seems odd that your `resultType` is `NSCountResultType` but you also `countForFetchRequest`... how do you count something that is itself a count? Does anything change if you delete the line with `resultType`?

Comment: Commented it out.  Same result.  Something is definitely messed up.  I can change name of entity to nonsense and get same number.

Comment: No need for the * in this line: `NSUInteger *numberBooks = [self retrieveNumBooks];` - just use `NSUInteger numberBooks = [self retrieveNumBooks];`

Comment: I realize I forgot to load managedobjectcontext.  That's why entity name had no effect.  Strange thing is why it gave weird number.  But now working.  Thx!

Comment: The `if ((itemsCount=NSNotFound)) {` line shold be `if ((itemsCount == NSNotFound)) {`, isn't it?